# Trying to run python in scottyhardy/docker-wine container points to a Windows directory

Tags: python, wine, docker

I have a number of programs that I want to run in a Docker container based on the `scottyhardy/docker-wine` image. When I do, it says it can't find `L"C:\\windows\\system32\\python3.exe"`. I started a container with /bin/bash and was able to verify that python 3.8 is installed and using python3 I can start a console just fine.

This is how I'm running it:

```
docker run -it \
  --rm \
  --env="DISPLAY" \
  --volume="${XAUTHORITY:-${HOME}/.Xauthority}:/root/.Xauthority:ro" \
  --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix" \
  --volume="/home/user/myapp/plugins/mypluginfolder:/home/wineuser/testfolder/mypluginfolder" \
  --volume="/home/user/testfile:/home/wineuser/testfolder/testfile" \
  --hostname="${hostname}" \
  --name="wine" \
  scottyhardy/docker-wine wine python3 -m home.wineuser.testfolder.mypluginfolder -m /home/wineuser/testfolder/testfile
```

I suspect my problem is that python is in the container but not in whatever wine is looking at as its space. I haven't worked with wine before so I'm at a bit of a loss. I also tried making that last line:

```
scottyhardy/docker-wine wine C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe
```

That resulted in `cannot find L"C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe`.

Most of my googling results in how to use wine from a command line, which doesn't quite work in the Docker container.

Any tips?

Comment: you may need to install the `wine` version of Python. what program are you trying to run?

Comment: @Esther - I didn't realize there is a wine version of Python. We've got a variety of plugins that we run on Windows but some of our users want to run things on Linux. Most plugins are python based and they work fine but some are not developed internally and we just have exes.